# How to set mouseclick property of textbox in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, textbox, mouseclick-event

When I click in textbox cursor position should be at where I click the mouse.

Currently after mouse click cursor is place at begining of text in textbox. Also when I hover clicking mouse on text in textbox hover text should be select. I think this should be default properties of textbox. How enable this properties. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The default behaviour of a TextBox *is* to put the cursor where you click - do you have any code which affects the TextBox?

Comment: Currently I dont code other than textchanged event. But this problem arise in every textbox even if if i put new textbox without any coding. Is their any option properties window?

Comment: Can you start a new project to see if you get the same behaviour in that? Just to check.

Comment: On your suggestion I create new project. Here textbox perform their default behaviour. There is no problem going.  But how can I find whats wrong in my current project? In my current project at evrywhere this problem is arised. My textbox default font is calibri.

Comment: So you need to track down which part of the code in the project is affecting all textboxes and making them behave the way you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

@AndrewMorton

When I open form using code

```
 With Form2
        .TopLevel = False
        Panel2.Controls.Add(Form2)
        .BringToFront()
        .Show()
    End With
```

This problem is arise.
If I open form like

```
 Form2.Show()
```

it works perfectly.
Is there any wrong.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).